# phpunit not generating coverage-xml file

Tags: phpunit

The following:

> phpunit "C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelTest\tests\ExampleTest.php" --coverage-xml "C:\Users\James\Documents\Test Logs"

is not creating an xml file for me.

I have also tried:

> phpunit "C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelTest\tests\ExampleTest.php" --coverage-xml "C:\Users\James\Documents\Test Logs\test.xml"

Any ideas where i'm going wrong? It simply runs the tests

*source of syntax*: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had placed the option in the wrong place. It needs to go after `phpunit` as described in the documentation (doh)
2. The `--coverage-xml` does not seem to work. however `--log-junit` does

The following command works:

> phpunit --log-junit "C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelTest\tests\ExampleTest.php" "C:\Users\James\Documents\Test Logs\log.xml"